# SMTP Send/Receive using external server

Tags: php, linux, email, smtp

I've created a php script that works in the following way:

1. New product received from billing in form of email
2. Current localhost smtp server receives the email and is configured to use ~/mail/new/ folder to put each email as a file
3. script reads the folder, parses each email file and then creates a project to track turn up

Complication: IT department wants me to use our internal MS Exchange server instead of the smtp server on the host to assist with spam issues.

So basically I need to either figure out 1 of 2 things. Easiest thing I can think of is configuring postfix to send/receive mail using the Exchange SMTP server, however I've only been able to find guides on how to send mail through a relayhost, not receive. I also found ssmtp, but again it's send only. I thought of using ssmtp to send and setting up some kind of cron every 10 minutes to check for received emails.

Second option is hard coding the SMTP details into the php script, which I am opposed to doing.

I'm open to suggestions. Server is Centos 7 x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using fetchmail + postfix to do this.

installed fetchmail

```
sudo yum install fetchmail
```

I had several users that were servicing different scripts, so I had to create ~/.fetchmailrc for each user with the following format:

```
poll imap.server.com proto imap:
        user "imapusername" is localusername here
        with password "password"
        folder "Custom Folder"
        keep
        ssl
        fetchall
```

Then, in each user's crontab, I put an entry to run fetchmail every ten minutes:

```
*/10 * * * * fetchmail
```

As for sending, I kept the solution of configuring postfix to use the imap server as relay host:

```
relayhost = [imap.server.com]
```

Our exchange server is configured to not relay mail from internal hosts to the mail spam gateway. IT is happy, scripts work.

Answer (score 0):

If the incoming messages are received by an exchange server, then you should be able to use PHP's built-in IMAP functions to fetch the messages from the mailbox on the exchange server.  See http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php.

Comment: Your answer took me in the right direction, however, I didn't want to have to migrate every script & application to php's imap. Explained in my answer.